# MySql REPLACE not executing just keeps on processing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a following MySql query:-

```
UPDATE tbl_page_items_options as pItem
                SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, '40c06a87f7713faba7b9631ab575f53d.png','40c06a87f7713faba7b9631ab575f53d.jpg')
            WHERE item_id = 3349
```

But it is not executing. Just keep on processing and halts the system. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is this table `tbl_page_items_options` ?

Comment: And if you need to replace just the extension why not `replace(option_value, '.png', '.jpg')`

Comment: The table is huge. But I am targeting a specific row with WHERE condition.

Comment: So you go for solution provided by Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* processing (in all likelihood).  It is just taking a long time.

You can speed this query by using an index:

```
create index idx_tbl_page_items_options_item_id on tbl_page_items_options(item_id);
```

Comment: Creating index will also take long if the table is huge?

Comment: @user2623251 . . . Yes.  But less time than the `update`.  And, then the update won't be locking the table for other queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply changing the option_value from `40c06a87f7713faba7b9631ab575f53d.png` to `40c06a87f7713faba7b9631ab575f53d.jpg`, then you can include this condition in the WHERE clause, thus reducing the number of rows that you select for the update.

```
UPDATE tbl_page_items_options
SET option_value = '40c06a87f7713faba7b9631ab575f53d.jpg'
WHERE item_id = 3349
AND option_value = '40c06a87f7713faba7b9631ab575f53d.png';
```

Establishing indexes on the columns `item_id` and `option_value` should speed up the query.

Comment: I have a JSON in the column. So I need to replace a string in the JSON string. That's why I am using the REPLACE.

Comment: Does the JSON string follow a specific format? If so, perhaps you can do a SUBSTRING on option_value. Ultimately, if you can limit the number of rows that you are selecting for update, then the query should perform faster.